# Find the limit of complex number

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I have $$Z_n = e^{-i({\frac{\pi}{2}+{\frac{1}{2n}}})}$$
Therefore, as $n \to \infty$,
$$\operatorname{\lim}Z_n = e^{-i{\frac{\pi}{2}}}$$
But the answer on the book is $i.$

Comment: $\dfrac1n\to0$ so the answer is $-i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$e^{-i\pi /2} =  \cos (-\pi/2) -i \sin(\pi/2)=-i$$

Thus the book has a typo.